# Runtime error upon running compiled Groovy code in IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: java, macos, groovy, intellij-idea, runtime-error

I keep getting this error when I attempt to run compiled Groovy code in IntelliJ IDEA 13:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7539 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/Insanity/Documents/Programming/Programming Languages/Groovy/Asteroids!/out/production/Asteroids!:/Users/Insanity/Desktop/:usr:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/ant-1.9.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/ant-antlr-1.9.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/ant-junit-1.9.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/ant-launcher-1.9.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/asm-4.1.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/asm-analysis-4.1.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/asm-commons-4.1.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/asm-tree-4.1.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/asm-util-4.1.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/bsf-2.4.0.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/gpars-1.1.0.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-ant-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-bsf-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-console-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-docgenerator-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-groovydoc-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-groovysh-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-jmx-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-json-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-jsr223-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-servlet-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-sql-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-swing-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-templates-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-test-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-testng-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/groovy-xml-2.2.2.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/ivy-2.3.0.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/jansi-1.10.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/jcommander-1.27.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/jline-2.10.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/jsp-api-2.0.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/jsr166y-1.7.0.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/junit-4.11.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/multiverse-core-0.7.0.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/qdox-1.12.1.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/servlet-api-2.4.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/testng-6.8.5.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar:local/opt/groovy/libexec/lib/xstream-1.4.4.jar:/Users/Insanity/Documents/Programming/Programming Languages/Java/Libraries/Java Game Libraries/slick/lib/slick.jar:/Users/Insanity/Documents/Programming/Programming Languages/Java/Libraries/Java Game Libraries/lwjgl-2.9.1/jar/lwjgl.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.insanity.asteroids.Init
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 15 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

By the looks of it the Groovy libs are not being found or something.

Comment: Is Groovy mentioned in the classpath?

Comment: Yep Groovy is mentioned in the classpath.

Comment: You seem to have groovy in `local/opt` with no preceding slash?

Comment: @tim_yates Are you referring to this line: /Users/Insanity/Desktop/:usr:local/opt/groovy/libexec

If so, it is a symlink on my desktop. On the Terminal slashes in folders and file names seem to be changed to colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was using a symlink that pointed to `/usr/local`. The error was fixed by changing the classpath to use the direct path of `/usr/local` instead of a symlink.

tl;dr: Don't set your classpath in IntelliJ using a symlink.